# How to use Mapbox Terrain RGB on the client side with Mapbox GL JS

Tags: leaflet, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl, mapbox-gl-leaflet

I am working on an Open Source project and our goal is to create an inundation map similar to the following:

https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/sea-level.html

https://labs.mapbox.com/bites/00307/?elev=1#4/29.92/-91.19

We would like to use Mapbox's elevation data using as RGB raster tiles ("Mapbox Terrain-RGB"). Found here: https://docs.mapbox.com/help/troubleshooting/access-elevation-data/#mapbox-terrain-rgb

I have built the structure of my Mapbox GL JS map and have hit the Terrain-RGB endpoint but am struggling to figure out how to consume this data using Mapbox GL JS; And complete RGB decoding in the client.

There is no available documentation or walkthrough for an inundation map on Mapbox currently so I am looking for some guidance.